# What graph theory textbook should I use?

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-economics, networks

I'm doing my Msc dissertation on production networks and business cycles and I want to learn graph theory. I need to be able to model the evolution of the network and identify equilibrium graphs.

Could someone recommend a textbook for me?

Comment: Related question : http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5155/where-to-start-with-social-networks

Comment: Do you want to learn about graph theory or applications of graph theory in economics?

Comment: The applications mostly.

Answer (score 3):

[Social and Economic Networks](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8767.html), by Matthew O. Jackson, and its associated MOOC at https://www.coursera.org/course/networksonline (videos from the 2014 session available, new live session starting September 2015).

Comment: You absolute legend!! This solves all my problems. I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a good, general graph theory reference, Doug West's textbook is the way to go. It's very readable, and has good material on network flows, matchings, and random graphs as well (which are particularly relevant in economic networks).

You may also be interested in reading some of Hans Haller's papers on economic networks. Haller has recently focused on strategic network formation. He isn't on Ideas, but his CV as of March 2015 is here: http://www.econ.vt.edu/cvsandresearch/hallercv.pdf

Networks, Crowds, and Markets is another good read: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/

Answer (score 2):

Another option is "[Connections](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8538.html)" by Sanjeev Goyal. It is more concise that Jackson's book (suggested by Martin Van der Linden), but also denser and, I therefore think, slightly less helpful when starting out with network models. But both are great books.

Comment: I've been using Jackson's book to write my dissertation, but have been looking at Goyals book as something i might graduate to when i have more time. Thanks for the input.